# MySQL multi-table delete with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

This does not work:

```
delete p,b 
from bookings b 
left join payments p 
    on p.booking_id=b.id 
where b.customer_id is null
```

It throws this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`busman`.`payments`, CONSTRAINT `payments_
>     booking_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`booking_id`) REFERENCES `bookings` (`id`))

But writing as two separate statements does work:

```
delete p 
from bookings b 
left join payments p 
    on p.booking_id=b.id 
where b.customer_id is null;

delete b 
from bookings b 
left join payments p 
    on p.booking_id=b.id 
where b.customer_id is null;
```

Is MySQL just not clever enough to realize I'm resolving the conflict in the same statement that I'm violating it, or is there another way to do this with one statement?

Comment: You cannot delete the `primary key` unless you have to delete first the foreign key from another table.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch If you re-read that first query, I'm deleting from both tables simultaneously. I'm trying to understand why this shouldn't work. After the query completes, no records are in violation of any constraints.

Comment: Yeah i got it.. It's Mysql execution on how its interpretation `Deleting records with left join`. Maybe the future version can do it hopefully.`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html : "If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might process tables in an order that differs from that of their parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides". So I'd use ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Thanks @fifonik! That's definitive. I'd accept that as an answer.